# Linq every occurrence of value, bind to ViewModel

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get a list of players and every team that said player is associated to and add it to my ViewModel.

**ViewModel**

```
public class PlayersViewModel
{
    public long PlayerID { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public List<long> TeamID { get; set; } //Players can be assigned to 1 or more teams
}
```

I have a few different datatables going on:

- PlayersInTeams (linking table)

> ```
> +------------+---------+
> |  PlayerID  | TeamID  |
> +------------+---------+
> | 1          | 10001   |
> | 1          | 10002   |
> | 2          | 10002   |
> | 3          | 10001   |
> +------------+---------+
> ```

- Players

> ```
> +------------+---------+-----------+
> |  PlayerID  | ForeName| Surname   |
> +------------+---------+-----------+
> | 1          | John    |  Doe      |
> | 2          | Pete    |  Noe      |
> | 3          | Evan    |  Soe      |
> +------------+---------+-----------+
> ```

So for the above example tables, Player 1 - John Doe should have an array of 2 teamIDs in the ViewModel `[10001, 10002].`

**Aim**

I'm trying to have a `List<PlayersViewModel>` with a collection of TeamIDs.

**Code**

```
public List<PlayersViewModel> GetPlayers()
{
    var playersInTeam = new PlayersInTeamsBLL();

    var pit = playersInTeam.GetPlayersInTeams();

    var playerDetail = Players;

    var list = from p in pit
        join team in Teams on p.TeamID equals team.TeamID // Only get teams that related to club
        join pd in playerDetail on p.PlayerID equals pd.PlayerID //Link a player to 
        where pd.IsArchived == false
        select new PlayersViewModel { TeamID  = team.TeamID, PlayerID = p.PlayerID, PlayerName = pd.Forename + " " + pd.Surname};

    return list.ToList();
}
```

I'm getting `null` PlayerIDs and obviously my TeamID isn't getting populated.

Any suggestions / solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var viewModels = playerDetail.Select(p => new PlayersViewModel()
{
  PlayerID = p.PlayerID,
  PlayerName = String.Format("{0} {1}", p.ForeName, p.Surname),
  TeamID = pid.Where(pidElement => pidElement.PlayerID == p.PlayerID)
              .Select(pidElement => pidElement.TeamID).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

In general it seems to me you're trying to tackle the problem from the wrong end. You want a list of players first, and then their teams second, not a list of player-team associations first, and player details second, so you should start with the `playerDetail` object (I assume it's an `IEnumerable` of all `Player` objects).

On a side note: consider that you can add a getter to your `Player` class which would give you the full name without the need to always concatenate the name and surname. Something like:

```
public string FullName
{
  get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.Surname); }
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right @Shaamaan. Just plugged your code in and it works beautifully. Yes you are right about player details, I was attacking it from the wrong end. 

Also, wonderful suggestion, I'll add that too. Thank you for all of your help! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: One more thing, @Jezzabeanz... it might just be me, so take this with a pinch of salt... but I found that using LINQ query syntax is only good when you have to do joins. The method syntax seems a lot clearer in most cases. But like I wrote - this might be purely subjective.

Comment: I completely agree, I only use the query syntax when doing joins, which I thought I had to do for some reason. Cheers!

Comment: @Jezzabeanz For reference: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/83057/linq-style-preference :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = yourContext.Players
        .Select(p => new PlayersViewModel 
        {
            PlayerID = p.PlayerID,
            PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
            TeamID = context.PlayersInTeams.Where(x => x.PlayerID == p.PlayerID)
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  group them using group by like this:

```
var teamsFinal = from p in pit
                 join pd in playerDetail on p.PlayerID equals pd.PlayerID 
                 where pd.IsArchived == false
                 group new {p,pd} by  new 
                                     { 
                                        pd.PlayerID ,
                                        pd.ForeName, 
                                        pd.SurName
                                     } into g
                 select new PlayersViewModel
                 {
                     TeamID = g.Select(x => x.p.TeamID).ToList(), 
                     PlayerID = g.Key.PlayerID, 
                     PlayerName = g.Key.ForeName + " " + g.Key.SurName
                 };
```

[Check this working Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cPxReQ)